# How to change height of List items in libgdx?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I use the libgdx widget List. As I understand it, the height of the list item corresponds to the size of the skin font. But I want to change the item height. The use of list.setScaleY() visually gave nothing.
Is it even possible?

Comment: How did you use `list.setScaleY()`?

Comment: i just set: list.setScaleY(1.5f); thus changing the coordinates of touching, but do not increase the visual line.